# Input gravity forms' entries in a database locally stores (created with python)

Tags: python, php, sqlite, gravityforms

I hope you are all doing alright.

Is it possible to connect a gform entry to a database created with Python and stored in my PC with a little variation of the following code?

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "input_fields", 10, 2);
function input_fields($entry, $form)
{
    $password = "password";
    $username = "username";
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbname = "db";
    $fname = $entry["12.3"];
    $lname = $entry["14.6"];
    $email = $entry["4"];
    $address1 = $entry["5.1"];
    $address2 = $entry["15.2"];
    $city = $entry["16.3"];
    $state = $entry["18.4"];
    $zip = $entry["17.5"];
    $bbd = $entry["7"];
    $upc = $entry["6"];
    $subject = $entry["10"];
    $question = $entry["2"];

$con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO wp_contacts (id, name, last_name, 
state, city, address, address_2, bbd, subscribe, upc, email, subject, 
comments, phone, user_ip, answer, answered_by, zipcode, category_id, 
active, contact_captcha, answered_date, dept, computer_name, created) 
VALUES ('', '$fname', '$lname', '$state', '$city', '$address1', 
'$address2', '$bbd', '', '$upc', '$email', '$subject', '$question', 
'', '', '', '', '$zip', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')");
}
```

I have tried creating a snippet with the following PHP code:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "input_fields", 10, 2);
function input_fields($entry, $form)
{
$dbname = "forms.db";
$fname = $entry["12.3"];
$lname = $entry["14.6"];

$con=mysqli_connect($fileadres);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO vragenlijst (f_name, l_name,) 
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname');
 }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely be possible! I think the best option for you would be to implement a custom [Feed](https://docs.gravityforms.com/what-is-a-feed/#:%7E:text=A%20feed%20is%20like%20a,visitor%20successfully%20submits%20your%20form.). Feeds essentially allow you to pipe any data from a form entry to another location, in your case, the local DB you created in Python.

In order to facilitate this, you'd likely want to create a new [GFFeedAddon](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gffeedaddon/) class. This class provides methods to do all sorts of add-on related things, but specifically you'll want to look at overriding the `process_feed()` method (scroll down to the "Processing Feeds" section of the docs page I linked above).

Within this method, you'll have access to all of the values submitted, which you can access via `$this->get_field_value()`. Once you have the values you want to work with, it's just a matter of connecting to your local Python database using whatever method you want and storing the values you retrieved from the entry.